# Javascript difference between {} and []

Tags: javascript

I am working on javascript and I run into this:

if i do

```
let object = {};
object.length
```

It will complain that object.length is undefined 
But

```
let object = [];
object.length
```

works

Any know why?

Thanks

Comment: Only Arrays have length.....  But you could do `Object.keys(object).length`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In JavaScript, virtually everything is an object (there are exceptions however, most notably `null` and `undefined`) which means that nearly all values have properties and methods.

```
var str = 'Some String';
str.length // 11
```

`{}` is shorthand for creating an empty object. You can consider this as the base for other object types. `Object` provides the last link in the prototype chain that can be used by all other objects, such as an `Array`.

`[]` is shorthand for creating an empty array. While also a data structure similar to an object (in fact `Object` as mentioned previously is in its prototype chain), it is a special form of an object that stores sequences of values.

```
typeof [] // "object"
```

When an array is created it automatically has a special property added to it that will reflect the number of elements stored: [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties). This value is [automatically updated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Relationship_between_length_and_numerical_properties) by certain methods while also used by others.

```
var arr = [];
arr.hasOwnProperty('length'); // true
arr.length; // 0
```

In fact there is nothing special about properties on arrays (although there are few if any good reasons to use them) aside from the engine using them for those methods.

```
var arr = [];
arr.foo = 'hello';
arr // []
arr.foo // "hello"
arr.length // 0
```

This is not true of an `Object` though. It does not have a `length` property added to it as it does not expect a sequence of values. This is why when you try to access `length` the value returned is `undefined` which is the same for any unknown property.

```
var obj = {};
obj.hasOwnProperty('length'); // false
obj.length; // undefined
obj.foo; // undefined
```

So, basically an array is a special data structure that expects a sequence of data. Because of this a property is added automatically that represents the length of the data structure.

BONUS: You can use `length` to trim an array:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
a.length; // 5
a.length = 2;
a; // [1, 2]
a.length; // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `[]` is an array object and the length is 0 because there are no elements. `{}` is an object and there is no property `length`.  The array object does have a property called `length`, thats why you see the number of elements when you call `[].length`

Comment: Then how do I get the length of an object at run time?

Also, I fixed my problem by using an array[] instead, but I still want to know object{} doesn't work for me. Everything stayed the same except I switched {} to []

Comment: @Telenoobies as stated by Simon H, `Object.keys(object).length`

Comment: @jbman223 this isn't very reliable though because properties on the prototype chain will not be enumerated with `Object.keys()`

Comment: @Telenoobies Also, it's important to understand the difference between an array and an object. Objects inherently don't have length because they aren't number-indexed.

Answer (score 2):

`[]` signifies an array in javascript, so it has length. `{}` is just declaring an object.

Comment: `java` !== `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

They're different things. One is an object, another is an array.

`{}` is an object, which has keys and values.
You can't necessarily determine the length of an object since its key-value pairs may not necessarily be numbers or indexed in any way.

`[]` is an array, which has numbered indices. It's pretty straightforward it has a length.

Comment: Technically speaking arrays *are* objects, as defined in the spec they are 'exotic' objects (which is also why arrays are pass-by-reference instead of pass-by-value)

Comment: Right, but javascript cant return the object size at run time with .length method?

Comment: `length` is a property that arrays have innately. An object has no concept of a length as it's not a container, and has no `length` property, so, no.

Comment: You're right, though the whole idea of arrays being objects is a lot more broad and I think there are plenty of online resources to help you understand the two. I was just trying to give a basic outline of the differences, since I'm assuming OP is just starting.

Comment: @Telenoobies edited my answer to explain why objects don't have lengths