# JavaScript difference between curly brackets and square brackets

Tags: javascript

What's the difference between **var = []** and **var = {}** in JavaScript?

Comment: [] -> array, {} -> object. Pleade read some books about JS, all of them will explain the difference :)

Comment: @JonasWilms could you give me some documentation about my question?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript difference between {} and \[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299172/javascript-difference-between-and)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[]` is an empty [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp) (i.e. with zero items).

`{}` is an empty [object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp) (i.e. with zero key-value pairs).

Answer (score 1):

[] : The square brackets are for **Arrays**.
{} : The curly brackets are for **Objects**.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some info about your doubts: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp