# How to arrange array inside array data in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have one array inside that I have some multiple array inside that I tried to arrange that array inside array but I dont know what is wrong ? so how to set array inside array properly? below arrayData is available.

```js
const arrayData = [
  form_id: 1,
  countTotal: 100,
  formName: 'Application Form',
  questions: [
    0: [
      questionName: 'what is your name ?',
      note: 'give firstname middlename and lastname also..',
      required: true,
      answer: 'my name is John dao',
      sequence: 0,
      questionType: 'long text',
      options: [],
    ]
    1: [
      questionName: 'select your gender ?',
      note: '',
      required: true,
      answer: 'Male',
      sequence: 1,
      questionType: 'Single Selector',
      options: [
        0: {
          option_id: 1,
          value: 'Male',
          sequence: 0,
          is_selected: true,
        },
        1: {
          option_id: 2,
          value: 'female',
          sequence: 1,
          is_selected: false,
        },
        2: {
          option_id: 3,
          value: 'Other',
          sequence: 2,
          is_selected: false,
        },
      ],
    ]
  ]
]
```

Comment: Arrays can only have numeric keys. You are using named keys. Use `{}` instead of `[]`.

Comment: if you use `{}`, it will return as object, not array. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299172/javascript-difference-between-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `arrayData` that you tried to make is **not an array** but **an object**. So contents should be in `{}` not in `[]`.

**Update**: If it is really an array containing object like that, you need to put an object in the array.

```js
[a: 1, b: 2]   // wrong
[{a: 1, b: 2}] // correct
```

2. property like `questions` is type of array but but you are setting *keys*. You can't do it manually like that.

```js
[0: 1, 1: 2] // wrong
[1, 2]       // correct
```

3. and item of `questions` should be an object so its content should be in `{}` not in `[]`.

```js
[a: 1, b: 2] // wrong
{a: 1, b: 2} // correct
```

```js
const arrayData = [{
  form_id: 1,
  countTotal: 100,
  formName: 'Application Form',
  questions: [{
      questionName: 'what is your name ?',
      note: 'give firstname middlename and lastname also..',
      required: true,
      answer: 'my name is khan, but i am not terrorist',
      sequence: 0,
      questionType: 'long text',
      options: [],
    },
    {
      questionName: 'select your gender ?',
      note: '',
      required: true,
      answer: 'Male',
      sequence: 1,
      questionType: 'Single Selector',
      options: [{
          option_id: 1,
          value: 'Male',
          sequence: 0,
          is_selected: true,
        },
        {
          option_id: 2,
          value: 'female',
          sequence: 1,
          is_selected: false,
        },
        {
          option_id: 3,
          value: 'Other',
          sequence: 2,
          is_selected: false,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
}]

console.log(arrayData)
```

Comment: it is works but if I want arrayData as array so how to make arrayData as array ?

Comment: his code was right, you need to make an object instead of array

Comment: @Akki If it is really an array, you need to put an object in the array. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this:

```
const arrayData = [
     form_id : 1,
     countTotal: 100,
     formName: 'Application Form',
     questions: [
                 [
                   questionName => 'what is your name ?',
                   note => 'give firstname middlename and lastname also..',
                   required => true,
                   answer => 'my name is khan, but i am not terrorist',
                   sequence => 0,
                   questionType => 'long text',
                   options => [], 
                 ],
                 [
                   questionName => 'select your gender ?',
                   note => '',
                   required => true,
                   answer => 'Male',
                   sequence => 1,
                   questionType => 'Single Selector',
                   options => [
                       { option_id: 1,
                         value: 'Male',
                         sequence: 0,
                         is_selected: true,
                       },
                       { option_id: 2,
                         value: 'female',
                         sequence: 1,
                         is_selected: false,
                       },
                       { option_id: 3,
                         value: 'Other',
                         sequence: 2,
                         is_selected: false,
                       },
                   ], 
                 ]
                ]
   ]
```

You shouldn't give the index manually because It already registered automatically.

```
array = ['data index 0','data index 1','data index 2'];
```

Besides, you can register your own index by using this:

```
array = [index1 => 'data index 1', index2 => 'data index 2'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Though `[]` are used for array's but your array is not containing array items instead are more of dictionary item. So either make it dictionary using `{}` parenthesis or add items like this and it will make your array a list of dictionary

```
 [
     {form_id : 1},
     {countTotal: 100},
      ....
 ]
```

and for array inside array , add like this

```
questions: [{  
                 questionName: 'what is your name ?',
                 note: 'give firstname middlename and lastname also..',
                 required: true,
                 answer: 'my name is John dao',
                 sequence: 0,
                 questionType: 'long text',
                 options: [], 
        },
        ....
        ]
```